# why Bitmap convert to byte[] will cause size increase?

Tags: android, bitmap

I have a funtion to compress a bitmap to below 32K.  When I got the returned Bitmap, converted it to byte[], the size increased.
code demo like below, The output is :

> before: 30
>   after: 85

did I use Bitmap in a wrong way?

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
int options = 100;
while (baos.toByteArray().length / 1024 > 31 && (count++ < 8)) { // compress to below 32K
    baos.reset();
    options -= 10;
    image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, options, baos);
}

ByteArrayInputStream isBm = new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray());
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(isBm, null, null);
LL.d("before: " + (baos.toByteArray().length/1024));
// here will return bitmap;
ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, output);
LL.d("after: " + (output.toByteArray().length/1024));
```

Comment: Before 30 bytes? After that 50 bytes?

Comment: before: 30
after: 85